# How to use dash (-) character in LIKE query

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database I have to filter records where name ends with `-N`,
but when I make the `WHERE` clause like in the following query it returns me no records, because `-` is a wild card character.

I am using this query in Oracle database:

```
 select * from product where productname like '%-N'
```

but the database has records that end with this product name

Comment: Oracle's `LIKE` operator only recognises two wildcard characters: `_` and `%`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697133/oracle-query-string-including-hyphen-character - OP in the linked question was mistaking `-` as a wildcard character, but realized their issue was elsewhere and unrelated to the `-`. I'd venture to guess that that's the case in this instance as well.

Comment: Please edit your question and include 1) sample data, 2) expected results, 3) results provided by your query. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

At first I thought that Oracle allows to specify a range `[a-z]` in the `LIKE` operator, and that needs to treat `-` in a special way. So, my suggestion was to escape the dash:

```
select * from product where productname like '%\-N' ESCAPE '\'
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

---

On the other hand, as @Amadan correctly said in the comment, Oracle's `LIKE` operator only recognises two wildcard characters: `_` and `%`.

It means that escaping the `-` should not change anything.

Which means that most likely the dash symbol in the query is not the same dash symbol that you have in your table. There are many-many-many different dashes and hyphens in unicode. Here are the most common. Hyphen-Minus (0x002D), En-Dash (0x2013, Alt+0150), Em-Dash (0x2014, Alt+0151).

```
- – —
```

Comment: not working saying missing or illegal escape character

Comment: @adeshsingh Read Vladimir's update. The `-` is **not** a wildcard character. Your issue must be something else.

Comment: hyphen or underscore? none of the document say hyphen is wildcard character

Comment: It's not "Oracle's LIKE operator" that behaves like that. This is how the LIKE operator was defined in the SQL standard. There is nothing special (or non-standard) about the way Oracle's LIKE works

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I had no idea there were many different dashes/hyphens and could not understand why my query returned no results when (using other queries) I could see with my own eyes the query "should" return several rows. Turns out the query and the table content had different dashes.

Answer (score 1):

`'-'` is *not* a wildcard for `like` (as mentioned elsewhere).

So, start with names that end in `'N'`:

```
where productname like '%N'
```

Does this do what you want?

If not, you can then go to a regular expression.  For instance, to find anything other than a digit or letter before the `'N'`:

```
where regexp_like(productname, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]N$')
```

You can refine `regexp_like()` if this doesn't return what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work as expected. Here's an example:

```
WITH cteData as (SELECT 'ABC-N' AS PRODUCTNAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'ABCN' AS PRODUCTNAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'ABC' AS PRODUCTNAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'DEFGHI-J-K-L-M-N' AS PRODUCTNAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'DEFGHI-J-K-L-M-' AS PRODUCTNAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'MY DOG HAS FLEAS' AS PRODUCTNAME FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM cteData
  WHERE PRODUCTNAME LIKE '%-N';
```

As expected, this returns:

```
ABC-N
DEFGHI-J-K-L-M-N
```

If you're not getting the results you expected there's something else going on that you haven't showed us.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d64e/32)

Best of luck.